# Using Spark Dataframe to iterate through records and concat the current value with previous value based on some condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm quite new to Spark and Scala coding. I'm currently working on Spark DataFrames. I have a requirement to iterate through the records and repeat the same value until the next condition meets. Please find below the example, I have only one column in the file given to me. The example has two types of values one is header data and the other is details data. The header data is always 10 char length and the details data is always 15 char length. I would like to concat the first 10 chars with the next record 15 chars till we reach the next 10 chars and so on...

```
df
---------------
1RHGTY567U //header data 
6786TYUIOPTR141 //detail data
6786TYUIOPTYU67 //detail data
T7997999HHBFFE6 //detail data
8YUITY567U      //header data 
HJS7890876997BB //detail data
BFJFBFKFN787897
GS678790877656H
BFJFDK786WQ4243
74849469GJGNVFM
67YUBMHJKH
VFJF788968FJFJD
HFJFGKJD789768D
GFJFHFFLLJFJDLD
```

I have tried this by collecting the DataFrame, looping through it and concatenating it with the other record as show below. The method I have followed is a costly operation as collect() is not advisable. I could use lag window function to concatenate the current value with the previous value but my scenario is little different.

```
val srcDF = spark.read.format("csv").load(location + "/" + filename)

   //Adding another column to the DataFrame which shows length of the value in the column
   var newDF = srcDF.withColumn("col_length", length($"_c0"))

   //Converting DataFrame to RDD
   var RDD = newDF.map(row => row(0).toString + "," + row(1).toString).rdd

   //Iterating through RDD to concatenate Header data with the detail
   for (row <- RDD.collect) {
      if (row.split(",")(1).toInt == 16) { Rec = row.split(",")(0).toString }
      if (row.split(",")(1).toInt > 16) {
         srcModified += Rec + row.split(",")(0).toString
      } 
      else {
         srcModified += Rec
      }
   }

   //Converting ListBuffer to RDD
   val modifiedRDD = sc.parallelize(srcModified.toSeq)
```

The output that I'm expecting is shown below:

```
new_DF
------

1RHGTY567U //header data 
1RHGTY567U6786TYUIOPTR141 //header data concatenated with detail data
1RHGTY567U6786TYUIOPTYU67 //header data concatenated with detail data
1RHGTY567UT7997999HHBFFE6 //header data concatenated with detail data
8YUITY567U      //header data 
8YUITY567UHJS7890876997BB //header data concatenated with detail data
8YUITY567UBFJFBFKFN787897 //header data concatenated with detail data
8YUITY567UGS678790877656H //header data concatenated with detail data
8YUITY567UBFJFDK786WQ4243 //header data concatenated with detail data
8YUITY567U74849469GJGNVFM //header data concatenated with detail data
67YUBMHJKH
67YUBMHJKHVFJF788968FJFJD
67YUBMHJKHHFJFGKJD789768D
67YUBMHJKHGFJFHFFLLJFJDLD
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incremental column can be added to Dataframe, and Window by incremental column will find  latest header, by "last" function:

```
val withId = originalDF.select($"value", monotonically_increasing_id().alias("id"))

val idWindow = Window.orderBy("id")
withId
  .withColumn("previousHeader",
      last( when(length($"value") < 15, $"value")
            .otherwise(null), true).over(idWindow)
          )
  .select(
      when($"value"=== $"previousHeader", $"value")
      .otherwise(concat($"previousHeader", $"value")).alias("value")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer really helped me to resolve my problem.